# Stringstream trouble

Tags: c++, loops, stringstream

so,i'm trying to do a conversion(integer to string) and then add this string 
with another.But it seems stringstream is not working..(it's normally working but the loop causes troubles)
I'm done with google 
& almost tried everything but can't get this code to work..Anyone help me :( ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;

string arr[n];
string a;
int i=0;
int s;
int c;

cin>>a;
arr[i] = a;
i++;
cout<<"OK"<<endl;
n--;

while(n--)
{
    cin>>a;
    s = 0;

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(arr[j] == a)
        {
            s = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    i++;

    if(s == 0)
    {
        arr[i] = a;
        cout<<"OK"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        c++;
        stringstream ss;

        ss<<c;

        string m = ss.str();

        a+=m;

        arr[i] = a;

        cout<<a<<endl;

        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++11, you can use `std::to_string(i);` where `i` is an `int`.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: `string arr[n];` -- This is not valid `C++`, as arrays in C++ must use compile-time expressions to denote the number of items.

Comment: "`string stream` is not working". It is doing **something**. What is it doing? What do you expect it to do? What is the difference?

Comment: You're using an uninitialized variable `c`.

Comment: No,i'm not using c++11 that's why all the trouble through stringstream @Tobias

Comment: yes,i need it thank you &NathanOliver

Comment: & i get the problem,thank u guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c` is uninitialized, you should initialize it, and also `s` before using:

```
int s = 0;
int c = 0;
```

You can't use non-const variables for array initialization, consider writing:

```
constexpr int MAX_STRINGS = 5;
string arr[MAX_STRINGS];
```

The loop trouble is here:

```
i++
```

You're going over the boundaries at the last element. Just move `i++` to the end of `while` loop.

Comment: yes,thank you..stream was working it's with my code :D